# T-SQL changing string

Tags: sql, sql-server

the nvarchar data in the column in my table is as follows

```
2020.05.26
...
```

I want to do it all like this

```
26.05.2020
...
```

with update commands. so permanently.

Comment: Depends on the SQL dialect you use

Comment: what does dialect mean

Comment: t-sql?...................................................................................

Comment: I know that this might not be an option in your particular case, but *please* seriously consider using a `date` column instead of an `nvarchar` column for dates. Yes, changing everything is a lot of work, but everything will be so much easier afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the '.', convert to `date` and apply a custom format string.

Like this:

```
select format( cast(replace(N'2020.05.26','.','') as date), 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

outputs

```
26.05.2020
```

To make a permanent change, using an SSMS query window connected to your database, first run:

```
begin transaction
update someTable set someCol = format( cast(replace(someCol,'.','') as date), 'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

then inspect result and verify the change

```
select top 1000 * from someTable
```

then commit the change

```
commit transaction
```